# How to programmatically populate a custom Layout that is included into another Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, adapter, baseadapter

I have a custom layout that I included in another layout. Now I want to set the views of the first layout from the activity that sets the bigger layout as its contentView. I thought about creating a baseAdapter but I am stuck. Here is what I have tried:

Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">
//...
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/offer_card_view"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                    <include layout="@layout/offer" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Sub layout (offer):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    tools:context="com.example.abdelrhmanghreeb.maftou7.Activities.admin.offers.NewOfferActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/offer_thumb_area"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/offer_thumb"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


                <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
                    android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    wheel:matProg_barColor="@color/primary"
                    wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/offer_thumb" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/offer_type"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/large_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/large_icon_size"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/offer_name"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_clearance"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/offer_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/offer_thumb"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/offer_type"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/offer_type"
                    android:hint="Offer Name"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxEms="300"
                    android:maxLines="1"

                    android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_font"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="NewApi" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/offer_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/offer_start_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" - " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/offer_end_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
<!--details-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offer_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Offer Details"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxEms="500"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/container_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

    <!--submit bar
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/submit_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_offer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Post" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </LinearLayout>-->
```

The activity:

```
    Public class MainActivity {
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.setContentView(R.layout.expanded_shop_profile_activity);
         //...
         offer_adapter mOfferAdapter = new offer_adapter(getApplicationContext());
         CardView offer_card_view = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.offer_card_view);
         offer_card_view.setAdapter(mOfferAdapter);
}
```

The Adapter I tried:
public class offer_adapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context _context;
private LayoutInflater infalInflater;

public  offer_adapter(Context context) {
    _context = context;
    infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View myView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View  convertView = myView;

    if (myView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer, null);
    } else {
        convertView = (View) myView;
    }

    initializeUniversalImageLoader();
    //getting the layout views
    offer_thumb = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_thumb);
    offer_type = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_type);
    final TextView offer_name = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_name);
    final TextView offer_start_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_start_date);
    final TextView offer_end_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_end_date);
    final TextView offer_details = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_details);
    wheel=(ProgressWheel) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
    wheel.setBarColor(Color.BLUE);
    wheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    offer_name.setText("someText");
    offer_start_date.setText("someText");
    offer_end_date.setText("someText");
    offer_details.setText("someText");
 //....
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Is this approach right? What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

`CardView` isn't an `AdapterView` so I don't see how you can call `setAdapter()` on it.  It is, however, a `ViewGroup`, so you can just call `addView()` every time you want to add a view.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by kris larson: CardView isn't an AdapterView. He is correct. Instead of that you can use is RecyclerView and If you want to populate Cardview you add it before scrollView(according to your requirement) in SubLayout and in Main Layout you can add RecylerView(ListView whichever suits you) and remove cardview.